# Detecting CTRL+Click in Webbrowser Control

Tags: vb.net, browser, iwebbrowser2

Ok! Here is the situation I have a application using Webbrowser Control, I want to detect the click events for anchors in web page. I dont need code, just the directions to look into.

---

### Edit

I didn't find any solution for the problem but found a hack in `Control.ModifierKeys`, this works until now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs][1]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

Comment: and where does WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs contains the information about CTRL being pressed or not!